# Why binary classification output in Keras is an array not a single value?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I have a model with the following architecture:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_45 (Conv2D)           (None, 298, 298, 32)      608       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_46 (Conv2D)           (None, 296, 296, 16)      4624      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_47 (Conv2D)           (None, 294, 294, 8)       1160      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_48 (Conv2D)           (None, 292, 292, 4)       292       
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_16 (Flatten)         (None, 341056)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_38 (Dense)             (None, 500)               170528500 
_________________________________________________________________
dense_39 (Dense)             (None, 250)               125250    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_40 (Dense)             (None, 120)               30120     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_41 (Dense)             (None, 20)                2420      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_42 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 21        
=================================================================

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I trained it and it was good, 
I tried to do a prediction like the following :

```
out = model.predict(xin,batch_size=1)
```

I thought that the output will be a single value, nevertheless it was:

```
print(out.shape)
(550, 1)
```

Now, I'm unable to understand this result, I thought it should be 1 element only.

Update: 
xin shape is (550,300,300,2)

Comment: And what is ```xin```? What do the docs say? I'm pretty sure, reading them and checking your shape of xin will clear up your confusion. (xin is probably a matrix describing 550 samples and you obtain 550 predictions).

Comment: What size is `xin`?

Comment: Thanks !, I didn't notice..... xin was wrong in shape !

Answer (score 0):

Found the error, was in xin wrongly shaped.